# C# Parsing a text file misses the first line of every text file

Tags: c#, parsing

I am making a number to music note value converter from text files and I am having trouble parsing text files in my C# code. The stream reader or parser seems to ignore every first line of text from different text files, I am learning from parsing CSV and assumed that I can parse text files the same way that I can parse CSV files. Here is my code:

```
static List<NoteColumns> ReadNoteValues(string fileName)
    {
        var allNotes = new List<NoteColumns>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line = "";
            reader.ReadLine();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] cols = line.Split('|');
                var noteColumn = new NoteColumns();
                if (line.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                double col;
                if (double.TryParse(cols[0], out col))
                {
                    noteColumn.QCol = col;
                }
                if (double.TryParse(cols[1], out col))
                {
                    noteColumn.WCol = col;
                }
            }
        }
        return allNotes;
    }
```

Here are the first 4 lines of one of my text file:

```
0.1|0.0|
0.0|0.1|
0.3|0.0|
0.1|0.0|
```

So every time that I have an output it will always skip the first line and move onto the next line. After it misses the first line it converts all the other values perfectly.

I have tried using a foreach loop but I end up getting an 'Index Out Of Range Exception'. Am I missing something/being stupid? Thanks for your time

Comment: Get rid of the `reader.ReadLine` before your loop.

Comment: reader.ReadLine() before the loop

Comment: If you copied that code for some CSV parsing algorithm it's likely that the `reader.ReadLine` before the `while` loop as intentionally skipping the first line because it expected that to be a line of headers for the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a call to `reader.ReadLine();` before your loop, which you don't assign to anything

Comment: Oh dear, how silly of me. Thank goodness for your good eyes! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Np, this happens to me all the time, sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes to find the issue,

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have already added `ReadLine()` before the while loop which skips the first line

Answer (score 1):

In order *to avoid* such errors (erroneous `reader.ReadLine()` in the beginning) get rid of `Reader`s at all and *query* file with *Linq* (let .Net open and close the file, read it line after line and do all *low level work* for you):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...  

static List<NoteColumns> ReadNoteValues(string fileName) {
  return File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .Where(line => !line.StartsWith('-'))
    .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
    .Select(cols => {
        var noteColumn = new NoteColumns();

        if (double.TryParse(cols[0], out var col))
          noteColumn.QCol = col;

        if (double.TryParse(cols[1], out var col))
          noteColumn.WCol = col;

        return noteColumn;  
     })
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Wow, this fixes the OP's issue and cleans up the code +1